# Book about a magic wizard who can see the color of emotions

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

It is about a boy who gets abandoned by his father and then then bought by a wizard wandering around in the forest. He learns magic from the wizard and can see the color of people’s emotions. There is a door in his house that leads him to another world.

Comment: Interesting, but this is a little bit vague. Are you able to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory?

Comment: For the scientifically inclined or simply those who might find it interesting and do not know... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia One example is you can feel sound (as in pain). Or a colour might hurt you. But it's more elaborate than that.

Answer (score 2):

The [*Jinx*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/107966-jinx) series, by Sage Blackwood.

> Set in a sentient primeval forest called The Urwald, the novel follows the adventures of a boy named Jinx who is abandoned in the forest and rescued by the wizard Simon Magus. Jinx grows up in Simon's house. After the wizard does a spell on Jinx that causes him to lose his ability to see others' emotions, Jinx runs away to seek help from the evil Bonemaster.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *Jinx* (Blackwood novel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(Blackwood_novel))</sub>

There is further description on the [author's website](http://www.sageblackwood.com/).